# How can you debug codenameone unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, netbeans, codenameone

So, codenameone uses its own unit-test framework which includes a Test Recorder from the emulator. All very cool. I have created unit tests by just having a new java class like this:

```
public boolean runTest() throws Exception {
    testSplitLines();
    return true;
}

public void testSplitLines() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("splitLines");
    String s = "Hello\nThere\nhow\n\nare\nyou";
    ArrayList<String> result = MyUtils.splitLines(s);
    assertBool(5 == result.size());
    assertBool("Hello" == result.get(0));
}
```

I can't work out how to debug it though - I only seem to be able to run it. I've tried "Debug Test File", but that appears only to be JUnit so doesn't help me!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that isn't supported right now.

However, since the testing framework is builtin you can copy the test into the project itself and just invoke the test class from the start method of your main class. This will allow you to debug the test using the standard debugging tools.

Comment: That's what I did in the end :)